# How to effect change from child to parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, parent-child

This is probably a fairly simple question, but I have had no luck researching it thus far. I have a child window that has a yes and no button on it. When I click no I would like a check box to become unchecked in the parent window (which is the main window of my program).

Is there anyway that I could do something like?:

```
//No Button
private void No_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NameOfParent.checkBox.Checked = false;
}
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654310/wpf-c-sharp-change-button-content-from-child-window) question but do not think that it exactly addresses my problem.

What is the correct way to go about this?

I've been using this to open my other windows:

**Parent Window - Current code:**

```
//Open new window
private void checkBox5_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       var newWindow = new ChildWindow();
       newWindow.button_no.Click += buttonNo_click;
       newWindow.Show();
}

//Unchecks Checkbox 5
private void buttonNo_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkBox5.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way but you don't want to do that. Create a proper ViewModel and do this via `DataBinding`, which is the right way to do it.

Comment: Or use a messaging framework and subscribe all necessary pieces to the correct messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the child window from the parent window:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new ChildWindow();
        window.buttonNo.Click += buttonNo_Click;
        window.Show();
    }
```

In the code of the parent window, include this click event for the child window's no button:

```
    private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //code to uncheck the checkbox goes here
    }
```

This turned out even simpler than the solution for Windows Forms that I've been using...and it appears to work in Windows Forms as well.

Comment: Is form2 supposed to be my child window? I'm just not sure what to put in the spots that say form. This is WPF by the way, not Win Forms.

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with WPF (yet) so I'm not sure how different they are. In Windows Forms, I open the child form by writing `ChildForm Form2 = new ChildForm();` and then below that, `Form2.ButtonClickAction += form_ButtonClickAction;`, which calls the void containing the code for what I want to happen when the `public event Action ButtonClickAction` is triggered by the button's click event in the child form.

Comment: All right, I created my own little WPF program and figured it out. Editing my answer to be relevant to WPF.

Comment: Where it says ChildWindow, do you need to include anything for that? I've been using var to open my window. I'll post my code.

Comment: I don't think using var would make any difference, the key part of it is the next line, which simply tells the parent form to run the buttonNo_Click method when buttonNo on the child form is clicked.

Comment: So there's nothing I have to do with the No button in the child window? With the `newWindow.button_no.click...` line I get an error that says: `The name 'buttonNo_click does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: ChildWindow is simply what I named the child window for the purpose of the example. `var window = new ChildWindow();` would do the same thing.

Comment: I understand that now, but I'm getting a compiler error for the action event.

Comment: Yes, you need to create the method for buttonNo_Click, which you can do simply by hovering the mouse over the error marking and clicking on "generate method stub for buttonNo_Click". You don't have to do anything in the child window except create buttonNo. The line `window.buttonNo.Click += buttonNo_Click;` reroutes the click action to the code of the parent window and tells it to run the method called buttonNo_Click, which won't exist in the current context until you create it. ;)

Answer (score -1):

On construction of the child window, simply add a parameter that is of the type of the parent window. 
Then when you are constructing your child window in the parent window code do the following (In The Parent Window Class):

```
ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow(this, other_param, other_param2.....);
ChildWindow.Show();
```

The keyword this will pass the parent window into the ChildWindow

Then you can store it into a class variable and access properties of it.

Child class constructor and parentWindow variable:

```
private ParentWindowType m_parentWindow = new ParentWindowType();
public ChildWindow(ParentWindowType parent, int other_param, string other_param2....)
{
    m_parentWindow = parent;
}
```

Then in other child class methods, such as your button click handler you can access properties from the parent window:

```
public void ButtonClickHandler(....)
{
    m_parentWindow.checkBox1.Enabled = true;
    m_parentWindow.checkBox1.Checked = true;
}
```

This way you can store the parent window within the child window, and always have access to it.
Its nice and clean and simple this way.  Ensure to make the parent window variable private in the child window class.

If made public, it would allow you to do funny things like

```
parentWindow.childWindow.m_parentWindow.childWindow etc......
```